# Prevent partial-caching of web resources

Tags: caching, resources, partial

I have a web page with a resource at a constantly changing address. For example, the web page might be at http_://www.mysite.com/?page=page1 and it might contain an image http_://www.mysite.com/?img=image999. Although both resources are on my site, I do not control the placement of particular images on particular pages.

I set headers for long caching on pages as well as images. But in case the user agent only caches web pages and not images (or for example, user clears cache and the image gets cleared from cache), the user agent will retrieve the page from cache and make a request for /?img=image999. However, at this point, the image is no longer at /?image=image999 but instead at say, /?image=image998. Thus the image won't be displayed to the user.

What is the solution to this problem? Here are the ones I could think of :-

1. Disable caching of both web pages and images. Worst solution.
2. Disable caching of web pages only. Better solution.
3. Remember on the server-side that image998 was once at image999 and if a request comes in for /?image=image999, redirect/transfer it to /?image=image998. Best solution but a pain to implement. EDIT: In fact, I now realize this is impossible in my situation *sadface*

My exact problem doesn't deal with images but with HTML5 videos. Specifically, on Google Chrome I notice that videos seem to be removed from the cache quite frequently even though I'm setting 1-year expiry dates on the cache. But I'm still interested in the solution for general resources regardless of Chrome's caching policies.

EDIT: To confirm, I'm using "dont revalidate" + "expires in 1 year" caching on both the web page and the image. Thus if a UA requests the web page (page1) + image (image999) once, it wont hit the server for subsequent requests and all is good. The problem happens when the image drops out of the UA cache but the web page remains. In this situation, the UA will *not* request the server for the web page, but *will* request the server for the image (image999). However, in the meantime, the image has changed URLs (image999 -> image998) and the server will return a 404. The result is that the UA will not display the image. How do I prevent this?

Comment: The html page that contains the link to img999 should change and the browser should request a new page instead of using the cached version since it won't get a NOT-MODIFIED HTTP header. I don't understand the problem. At the end of the question you say that the problem is that it's not cached, which is not what you said in the beginning of the question (having a link to an outdated resource)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is the web page which is being cached, but not the image. I need both to be cached.

Comment: Also, the reason I don't want the web page to be re-downloaded when the image URL changes is that the image is still the same, just at a different URL. As I said, the real problem is not with images but with HTML5 videos, and the constant-changing URL is a hot-linking prevention measure. But if a client has already requested the web page + video, I don't care if they cache it for all eternity.

Comment: Lastly, this is a full cache, not a revalidate-cache. There are no E-Tags and 304 headers involved. The UA won't validate the web page with the server but use the one from the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, these are the solutions I can think of if I restrict myself to using the Expires header :-

1. Disable caching for both web pages and images.
2. Only enable caching for images. Every request for the web page will be handled by the server but requests for cached images will not hit the server.
3. Enable caching for both web pages and images. For requests to outdated images, send a "301 Moved Permanently" response with the location of the new image and pray the UA caches it.
   (My tests show that Google Chrome does not cache 301 requests or the content it is redirected to regardless of the Cache header)

For my problem, I have given up on using the Expires Header and am instead using ETag for both web pages and images. This way I don't have to handle requests for outdated images.